# How to use GBDT with EFB or GOSS with EFB in LightGBM? or is it implemented by default?

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

The paper for Lightgbm talks about goss and efb, I want to know how to use these together. I know of the hyper-parameter 'boosting' can be used to set boosting as gbdt, or goss, or dart. But how to use this with efb or is efb implemented by default and we have a choice of choosing boosting parameter.